# Creating new object from Guzzle response

Tags: php, oop, guzzle

I'm learning OOP PHP and am using Guzzle to make an API call and would like to create an object from a class I have defined (Coverage) from the response.

My Guzzle request looks like

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://www.example.com']);
$response = $client->request('GET', '?key=value&key=value');
$array = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

I then instantiate a new Coverage object like

```
$coverage = new Coverage($array);
```

My class looks like

```
class Coverage {

private $postcode;
private $headline;

function __construct(array $array)
{
    $this->setPostcode($array['locationValue']);
}
```

with getters and setters for the private variables.   As you can see I am passing the json_decoded Guzzle response
to the Coverage constructor but I was hoping to be able to pass the Guzzle reponse object itself to the 
Coverage constructor for example something like

```
function __construct(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $response)
```

or

```
function __construct(GuzzleHttp\Client $response)
```

My questions are:
1) Am I right to want to typehint a Guzzle class in the Coverage constructor rather than just using a general 
array which results from the json_decode of Guzzle's getContents method?

2) If I am right to do this which Guzzle class should I be using in the Coverage constructor?

Many thanks for any help!

Edit:  The comment from @Shaun Bramley sorted this for me perfectly!

Comment: I dont see why your class should depend on guzzel if all it really wants is the data

Comment: @Steve thanks for the reply.  It's just that the class will only be getting this data from Guzzle so it felt like I could be stronger on defining what should go into the class rather than just a general array

Comment: If all you are interested in is the response object, then your typehint should be Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface.  This way you place your dependency upon the contract rather than the implementation of said contract.

Comment: @ShaunBramley great that works perfectly! Many thanks!